# Get two variables from a reading file class without duplicating code

Tags: java

I have created a class called ReadFile to load the data (numbers and number of elements) from multiple files to 2 arraylist to store both numbers of number of elements. How can I get both the number of elements which is 4 and the following numbers without duplicating the reading file codes?

Sample input file

4

1 10 9 8

```
public class ReadFile {


   public List <Integer> getNumbers(){
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        File folder = new File("/Users/Mary/NetBeansProjects/Sample/src/program/pkg4/Input");

        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            try{
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                String numberOfElement = reader.readLine();
                String line = reader.readLine();                  
                for (String s : line.split("\\s+")) {                        
                    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
                }
                reader.close(); 
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR: There was a problem reading the file.\n" + e.getMessage());
            }  
        }    
        return numbers;
    }      

    public List <Integer> getElements(){
        List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();

        File folder = new File("/Users/Mary/NetBeansProjects/Sample/src/program/pkg4/Input");

        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            try{
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                String numberOfElement = reader.readLine();                       
                elements.add(Integer.parseInt(numberOfElement));

                reader.close(); 
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR: There was a problem reading the file.\n" + e.getMessage());
            }  
        }    
        return elements;
    }  


}
```

Comment: make a function that returns the entire file as string an call it to parse the list

Answer (score 0):

You can do as @jonathan Heindl suggested (read the entire fie into a String), or you can at least move the creation of the reader outside the two methods:

```
public void parseFile()) {
   File folder = ...;
   for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
      try {
         // create reader for this file
         ...
         int number = getNumber(reader);
         List<Integer> = getElements(reader, number);
      } catch( ... ) {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

You may even want to put the element list in a map keyed with the file name.It is not clear from your comments whether there are multiple lists in a single file, so you may need to do something different to handle that case.

Comment: I got this part here. However, if I want to get the elements and numbers from the main class. What should I do?